# How can I check if telegram session is currently in use?

Tags: telethon

**Is there a way to check if session is in use?**

I want to make sure that I do not use a session if it is already in use on a different IP address.

I am currently using `telethon-session-sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this to get active session:

```
GetAuthorizationsRequest()
```

Comment: didn't know that exists.. thanks! 
sadly still requires using a client. I was wondering if there is a way to query session store and see if session is in use

Marking it as correct (congrats on first stack overflow answer!) as it seems the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can make some request, if session down, you will get exception